# I am facing issue in search word end with "/" forward slash "Non-Conformity" in solr search engine

Tags: solr

I am facing issue in search word `"Non-Conformity"` in solr search engine that word end with `"/"` forward slash.

This is the url I used to search

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/sms/select?q="Non-Conformity"
```

key word  -  `"Non-Conformity"`  or `"Non-Conformity/"`   (not working)

Key word -  `"Non-Conformity/Deficiency"` (working)

key word available in document - `"Non-Conformity/Deficiency (NCD) Report for Class audits/surveys"`

Comment: what is the field type applied on the field? Did you applied any tokenizer to the text?

Comment: Hi abhijit thanks for your comment i am not applied any token to the text

Comment: Thats the issue here...Apply the standard tokenizer with lowercase filter. Re-index the data and check

Answer (score 0):

Apply the below field type to your field.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Your field would be like

```
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
          </analyzer>
```

If you analyse the same in admin page you will find the text is matching.

[image: screenshot]